# Get the nested div contents starting from the div with a specific id

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following div with `id="participant"` :

```
<div id="participant" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="">
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="question-container">
         <div class="question-group">
            <h5 class="question">
               Organisation
            </h5>
            <div class="answer">
               <p>Ministerio de Hacienda [Ministry of Finance]</p>
               <p>Consejo de Contadores Públicos del Paraguay (Consejo) [Council of Public Accountants of Paraguay]</p>
               <p>Central Bank of Paraguay – Superintendence of Banks</p>
               <br>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="question-group">
            <h5 class="question">
               Role of the organisation
            </h5>
            <div class="answer">
               <p>The Ministry of Finance has authority to establish accounting standards for all entities in Paraguay other than banks and financial institutions.&nbsp; </p>
               <p>The Consejo is the professional association of public accountants in Paraguay.&nbsp; The Consejo advises the Ministry of Finance with regard to accounting standards.</p>
               <p>Accounting standards for banks and other financial institutions are established by the Central Bank of Paraguay.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="question-group">
            <h5 class="question">
               Website
            </h5>
            <div class="answer">
               <p>Ministry of Finance: <a href="http://www.hacienda.gov.py" target="_blank">http://www.hacienda.gov.py</a></p>
               <p>Consejo: <a href="http://www.consejo.com.py" target="_blank">www.consejo.com.py</a></p>
               <p>Central Bank: <a href="http://www/bcp.gov.py" target="_blank">http://www/bcp.gov.py</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="question-group">
            <h5 class="question">
               Email contact
            </h5>
            <div class="answer">
               <p>Consejo: <a href="mailto:consejo@consejo.com.py">consejo@consejo.com.py</a><br>
                  Central Bank:
               </p>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="mailto:afranco@bcp.gov.py">afranco@bcp.gov.py</a> and <a href="hcentu@bcp.gov.py">hcentu@bcp.gov.py</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:jjimenez@bcp.gov.py">jjimenez@bcp.gov.py</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mailto:hcolman@bcp.gov.py">hcolman@bcp.gov.py</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the content of each div with `class="question"` and `class="answer"` starting from the `<div id="participant">`  because I have many div with the same structure and CSS so I can distinguish between them with the `id`

This is my expected output :

```
Organisation Ministerio de Hacienda [Ministry of Finance]
             Consejo de Contadores Públicos del Paraguay (Consejo) [Council of Public Accountants of Paraguay]
             Central Bank of Paraguay – Superintendence of Banks
Role of the  The Ministry of Finance has authority to establish accounting standards for all entities in Paraguay other than banks and financial institutions.
organisation The Consejo is the professional association of public accountants in Paraguay.  The Consejo advises the Ministry of Finance with regard to accounting standards.
             Accounting standards for banks and other financial institutions are established by the Central Bank of Paraguay.
Website      Ministry of Finance: http://www.hacienda.gov.py
             Consejo: www.consejo.com.py
             Central Bank: http://www/bcp.gov.py    
Emailcontact Consejo: consejo@consejo.com.py
             Central Bank:
             afranco@bcp.gov.py and hcentu@bcp.gov.py
             jjimenez@bcp.gov.py
             hcolman@bcp.gov.py
```

This is my work so far :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
# Site URL
url = "https://www.ifrs.org/use-around-the-world/use-of-ifrs-standards-by-jurisdiction/paraguay"
# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text
# Parse HTML code for the entire site
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
divs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id": "participant"})
disp = []
d=[]
for c in divs : disp.append(c.find('div', attrs={'class': 'question-group'}))
for t in disp : d.append(t.h5.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the final print formatting, something like this should work:

```
questions = [q.text.strip() for q in soup.select('div#participant h5.question') ]
answers = [a.text.strip() for a in soup.select('div#participant div.answer')]
for q, a in zip(questions,answers):
    print(q,": ",a)
    print('---')
```

Output:

```
Organisation :  Ministerio de Hacienda [Ministry of Finance]
Consejo de Contadores Públicos del Paraguay (Consejo) [Council of Public Accountants of Paraguay]
Central Bank of Paraguay – Superintendence of Banks
---
```

etc.